# String to date in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, date

I have a JSON response coming with the object of `'20180715'` and I need to convert that `string` to `date`, for example:

```
let dateString = '20180715';
```

I tried Date `testdate = new Date (dateString);` //fails.

How can I convert it to a date object in TypeScript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the **actual structure** of the date in the string **doesn't change**, you can just simply get the parts of the string using the [**`.substr`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) function.

Keep in mind, that the [**month is 0-based**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), hence the month have to be decreased by 1.

```js
const dateString = '20180715';
const year = dateString.substr(0, 4);
const month = dateString.substr(4, 2) - 1;
const day = dateString.substr(6, 2);
const date = new Date(year, month, day);

console.log(date.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you Rick! Yes the structure of the date string will be same. That works perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use RegEx to parse. Notice the decremental operator (`--`) for the month, since Date indexes the month at 0.  For anything more advanced, please refer to moment.js, which includes many formatting templates.

```js
const re  = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
const str = '20180715';
if (re.test(str)) {
  const dt = new Date(RegExp.$1, --RegExp.$2, RegExp.$3);
  console.log(dt);
}
```

Comment: This is an abuse of post decrement operator. `RegExp.$2 - 1` is much better.

Comment: @SalmanA that would work too, but it is not an abuse of the post-operator, it is a pre-operator and this is one way it was intended to be used where order of operation is important. Other solutions, like yours, would also work — the decision to do so comes down to preference and styling guides.